# Spring MVC3 @SessionAttributes and @ModelAttribute will automatically get value from request

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I’m trying to develop a Spring MVC application, now I encounter a question. When login successful I add the User entity to session and call `http://localhost:8080/user` to get the session user. Everything is OK here. But if I call the URL like this `http://localhost:8080/user?username=testuser` then the session user's username will change to testuser. What should I do that just get current user from session?

The code likes below

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    // ...Getter and Setter...
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
@SessionAttributes("current_user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User testSession(@ModelAttribute("current_user") User user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Response of `http://localhost:8080/user`

```
[{"id":1,"username":"aaa111"}]
```

Response of `http://localhost:8080/user?username=testuser`; it should be same as above, but is

```
[{"id":1,"username":"testuser"}]
```

Comment: `@SessionAttributes` is only meant to store objects in the session in between requests, it isn't intended to get access to session variables in different/multiple controllers. Next to that when using `@ModelAttribute` it means you want to use the object to do binding which is exactly what is happening here. I suggest you to don't use `@SessionAttributes` to get access to arbitrary objects in the session as that isn't its intend. Also I would suggest instead of rolling your own security use Spring Security instead this integrates nicely with the Servlet API.

Comment: Thank you very much.My understanding was wrong.you mean it is a wrong way to get session stored object? Can you tell me how to get seession object in Spring mvc,use session.getAttribute()?Spring Security is a good choice.

Comment: You still get and put objects in the session yuorself by using `session.[get|setAttribute`. To get the session just add a method argument of the type `HttpSession`. If you are comfortable with Spring MVC you could also create your own `MethodArgumentResolver` which operates on an annotation (for instance `@CurrentUser`) which gets the user for you. Then you can just add your `User` as an argument to the method and place the `@CurrentUser` annotation. But if you use Spring Security it already provides something similair due to the Servlet API integration.

Comment: Thanks a lot.it is what I Need.i will try the these two method.

Comment: I've put my comments into an answer with a bit more context and code samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@SessionAttributes` annotation isn't intended for this. Its intend is to store objects in the session during http requests. Imagine a lengthy database call to retrieve an object you don't want to retrieve this object each time but probably reuse an existing one. The object is to be intended to be used as a `@ModelAttribute`, this annotation indicates that you want to use this object for binding (i.e. you have a form to change attributes of the object). When you are finished with the editing of the object you should make this clear by calling `setComplete()` on the `SessionStatus` object. See also [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html).

You want to store an object in the session and retrieve it when you need it. For this use the `HttpSession` in the normal way of calling `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`. To obtain the current `HttpSession` you can simply add a method argument of the type `HttpSession` and it will be injected for you. (See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) for a list of supported method arguments).

```
public void myRequestHandlingMethod(HttpSession session) {
     User currentUser = (User) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
}
```

Or as you are already using Spring you could use the [`WebUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html) for convenience. You can use the `getSessionAttribute` or `getRequiredSessionAttribute` methods to obtain the value from the session.

```
public void myRequestHandlingMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
     User currentUser = (User) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute("currentUser", request)
}
```

Another solution would be to extend Spring MVC. Spring MVC uses a [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to handle all the different types of method arguments. This mechanism is pluggable. You could create an annotation `@CurrentUser` and create a `CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that will retrieve the user from the session and injects it in that place. You could then simply add your current user to your method signature.

```
public void myRequestHandlingMethod(@CurrentUser User user) { ... }
```

Configure the custom argument resolver

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:argument-resolvers>
          <bean class="com.yourcomponany.app.web.CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver />
     </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

It also looks like you are rolling your own security framework, which I would advice against. Instead I would suggest using [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) instead. Advantage of this is that this provides integration with the Servlet API allowing for retrieval of the current `Principal` by either doing it yourself (`request.getUserPrincipal()`) or simply adding a method argument of the type `java.security.Principal`. It also comes with a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which allows you to obtain the current Spring Security `Authentication` object.

Answer (score 0):

try to get session value in controller from servlet request like below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
@SessionAttributes("current_user")
public class UserController{
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User testSession(HttpServletRequest request){
        //false means do not create new session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        return session != null?session.getAttribute("current_user"):null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks first.yes,it is a good way to get session user;but i want to use Spring annotation to deal with.do you know any other way? not session.getAttribute().

Comment: SessionAttributes scope is to that handler only where it is declared.It can not be accessed in other controllers.

Comment: thanks,My understanding was wrong about SessionAttributes and ModelAttribute.@M. Deinum Said very clear.Thanks for all